# Custom template tage taking context: why is context a RequestContext instead of a dictionary?

Tags: python, django

I have many custom tags taking context:

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
```

For example:

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True) 
def get_items(context):
    return context['obj'].items.all()
```

But apparently that `context` object is not a dictionary like the one returned by `view.get_context_data`, but instead `context` is a `RequestContext` object which is more of a list of dictionaries with some entries and nested data. The context data is buried in there in some nested structure, but I have no idea how to access it.

The docs suggest that if you have the following context data in your view:

```
context = {'obj': instance}
```

When you access `context['obj']` in your custom tag function you will be accessing that same context. But this doesn't seem to be the case.

Why is `context` a `RequestContext` instead of a dictionary of data, just like the docs suggest?

How can I access my context data in my custom tags then?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequestContext implements the dictionary interface. It *is* the same as that passed from the view which you normally use in the template. You just access your items like any other dictionary, and `context['obj']` will work fine.

Comment: My issue is that the context object used in the custom tag doesn't look at all like the context dictionary used in the view. The one in the custom tag is a list of nested lists and dictionary, and the data I want to use is in one of them. I said all this before, not sure if it was understood. Could rendering templates within templates be related to the problem?

Comment: It was perfectly understood, but completely irrelevant. Django always converts the dictionary you pass from the view into a RequestContext. You access it like any other dictionary.

Comment: Actually turns out the problem was entirely different. A declared template variable had the same name than the custom tag function so it was being overriden in the context, leading to faulty behavior. Accepted your answer anyway.